# SQL conditional grouping without using cursors

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have a table containing a list of people and a duration value, and I need to add up the total duration for each person in the table, and also display the number of records for each person.

```
PersonTable
id int
name nvarchar(max)
duration decimal(18,2)

SELECT name, sum(duration) as TotalDuration, count(*) as NumRecords
FROM PersonTable
GROUP BY name
```

Unfortunately I also need to ensure that no person is placed in a group with a duration of more than 3 hours. If there are enough records for a certain individual that their total is > 3 hours, then I need to generate 2 groups for that person, or as many as is required to keep the total under 3. No single entry in the base table contains duration > 3, so a valid set of groups is always possible.

Test data for clarity:

```
id, person,     duration
1,  John Smith, 2hrs
2,  John Smith, 1hrs
3,  John Smith, 1hrs
4,  John Smith, 2hrs
1,  Jane Doe,   1hrs
1,  Jane Doe,   1hrs
1,  Jane Doe,   2hrs
8,  Jack Foo,   1hrs
```

Output: (Sequence number to identify distinct groups of the same person)

```
name,    Total Duration, Num Records, Sequence Number
John Smith, 3hrs,        2,           1
John Smith, 3hrs,        2,           2
Jane Doe,   2hrs,        2,           1 
Jane Doe,   2hrs,        1,           2
Jack Foo,   1hrs,        1,           1
```

This issustrates the basic problem. In practice there are more fields to group on, and I also need to enumerate the IDs of the base records as these will be used in a later stage.

My current solution is to just use cursors to iterate over the sorted table, and output new groups to a temporary table when the accumulated total hours exceeds 3. The temorpary table also includes a column of comma separated id values for each row of the base table contributing to the grouping.

However I'm wondering if there's a better (no cursors) solution to this sort of problem.
Would it also be possible to join the aggregate back to the base table, so I have a table of every record, plus a sequence number, allowing me to group on the person and sequence number to reproduce the table above? This would be a much better solution than producing comma separated id lists which are used to find the original records in a later stage of the process.

Comment: Does the table has a `Primary Key` or some other column that will be used for the ordering and grouping?

Comment: Yes, a plain auto-increment id column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid there isn't a way of doing what you want with standard SQL.  The issue is the following: if you group rows by certain attributes, this will always reduce each row group to one row; if you don't group, then you will have as many rows as in the original.  There is no way to reduce a group of three rows down to two rows.

Joining the base table to the grouped aggregate on the name column doesn't help because, again, you get as many rows as the base table.  Filtering the result of this join doesn't help either, because the join adds the same information to every row with the same name, and thus doesn't allow you to discriminate between them any more than before the join.

> Would it also be possible to join the aggregate back to the base table, so I have a table of every record, plus a sequence number, allowing me to group on the person and sequence number to reproduce the table above?

If your sequence numbers are unique within each name group, grouping by name and sequence number will be equivalent to not grouping at all.  So you need non-unique sequence numbers, i.e., some rows with the same name need to get the same sequence number; but the killer is that for an assignment of sequence numbers to reproduce the result, the sequence numbers must be assigned so that rows with the same name and sequence number never have durations whose sum > 3.  But if you could do that, you could use that to solve the problem already!

I really think your cursor solution is the most reasonable thing to do.  Pure SQL probably can't solve this, because it is unable to reduce a group of rows down to multiple rows.

Comment: So there's no solution? That answers the question then.